# Sorting multiple dataframes all at once in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

**Problem:** I see a lot of posts about sorting data frames by multiple factors but not many on how to sort several data frames by the same thing.

**Goal:** I'd like to sort multiple data frames by a single column so I can go on to join them (I know there is better way to merge so if you can answer that, it will also help.

My data frame looks like:

```
Country Meat per capita (kg/person)
40  Croatia 66.3
43  Czech Republic  83.4
44  Denmark 95.2
62  Germany 88.1
75  Iceland 86.2
111 Montenegro  57.7
117 Netherlands 85.5
124 Norway  66
147 Serbia  45.2
```

Each data frame all have the same countries as the first column (not considering index) with varying second columns: height, average meat consumption per capita, and average milk consumption per capita.

I tried just sorting each and every data frame but I would like to sort them all in fewer lines of code.

**Code:**

```
df_tall=df_tall.sort_values(by=["Country"], ascending=True) #sort tables by country to match up and merge
df_short=df_short.sort_values(by=["Country"], ascending=True)
dfm_tall=dfm_tall.sort_values(by=["Country"], ascending=True) #sort tables by country to match up and merge
dfm_short=dfm_short.sort_values(by=["Country"], ascending=True)
dfd_tall=dfd_tall.sort_values(by=["Country"], ascending=True) #sort tables by country to match up and merge
dfd_short=dfd_short.sort_values(by=["Country"], ascending=True)
```

Bonus: If you know how to merge them all by Country

Thank you for the help! I am just learning Python now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically loop through the dataframes and sort:

```
dfs = (df_tall, df_short, dfm_tall, dfm_short, dfd_tall, dfd_short)
for df in dfs:
    df.sort_values('Country', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

To merge them:

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on='Country', how='outer'), dfs)
```

Comment: You'll either need to sort each `DataFrame` inplace or create a new `list` containing the sorted version of each dataframe.

Comment: @CameronRiddell good point, I forgot you need to use inplace here. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidErickson and Cameron Riddell!